# How to get fixed number of data from json api in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

See Below Code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.names = response.data.records;
         });
});
```

In above Example We wrote the code for getting all data in **records** are stored in **names** but the requirement is first 5 data should be stored in **names**.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: So will your API always return back the full data and then you need to slice the data and store only the first 5 items? Or are you looking at changing your API?

Comment: No I don't want to change API. If possible to get 5 data from json api

Comment: Can you share the json format that you are getting from the API? Is it an Array or Object?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php

Comment: You can take a look at the answers given below, they should will solve your issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you can just do [*slice*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) from response records

```
$scope.names = response.data.records.slice(0,5);
```

Sample:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
         .then(function (response) {
             $scope.names = response.data.records.slice(0,5);
         });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersCtrl">
  <pre ng-repeat="name in names">{{$index+1}}: {{name|json}}</pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do it -

1. Make server side changes to get five records only (I think you dont want to use this).
2. On client side you can use the below code

Sample:

```
$scope.names=[];
$.each(response.data.records.slice(0,5), function(i, data) {
    $scope.names.push(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use slice

```
$scope.names = response.data.records.slice(0,5);
```